# predicate with Prolog

Tags: prolog

I have to write a program which has a predicate `p(A,B,C,D,E,F)`. A,B,C,D,E,F are lists.
A contains D, E and F. (Something like A and B is D, A and C is E) F contains A without D and E.
And also elements in list F are in pairs (example if A contains [a,b,c] then F would contain [a,a,b,b,c,c].)

So.. I can't get where to start. I have read tutorial and still.. I don't quite get it.

example:

```
A is [a,b,c,d,e,f,g]  
B is [a,c,d,q,w]  
C is [e,d,g,m,n]  
D is [a,c,d]  
E is [e,d,g]  
F is [b,b,f,f]
```

Comment: add a complete example. When should your predicate be true for instance?!

Comment: A is [a,b,c,d,e,f,g]
B is [a,c,d,q,w]
C is [e,d,g,m,n]
D is [a,c,d]
E is [e,d,g]
F is [b,f]

Comment: but `F` should contains "pairs"?

Comment: Yes, but how should `A`, `B`, `C`, `D`, `E` and `F` get their values. Is it testing, if so what is to be tested? Or is it building, again if so what is to be built? There must be some rules for it. what are they?

Answer (score 4):

> A contains D, E and F

Sounds like you would want to have a look at [`member`](http://www.gprolog.org/manual/gprolog.html#htoc202) and [`append`](http://www.gprolog.org/manual/gprolog.html#htoc201).

> Something like A and B is D, A and C is E

This could probably be solved with something similar to `append(A, B, D)` ("`D` is the concatenation of `A` and `B`") and `append(A, C, E)` ("`E` is the concatenation of `A` and `C`").

> F contains A without D and E.

Use `append` to find out what `F` is. Something like `append(FwithoutPairs, A, DandE)` and then create a `pairsOf` predicate, that looks something like

```
pairsOf([], []).
pairsOf([H, H | T], [H | S]) :- pairsOf(T, S).
```

Comment: sorry.. but I still don't get it.

Comment: shouldn't I use intersection?

Comment: @Kaspars `append` concatenates two lists. So "`append([1, 2], [3, 4], X)`" binds X to `[1, 2, 3, 4]`.

Comment: As per his example, the OP wants D to be the intersection of A and B, not the concat of A and B. So D is a list of all elements that are both in A and in B

Answer (score 0):

In addition to [aioobe's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4261056/7831383) :

> Something like A and B is D, A and C is E

```
p(A,B,C,D,E,_F):-
    intersection(A,B,D),
    intersection(A,C,E).
```

You would eventually need to order the lists but `intersection/3` seems more accurate.